# Div Float Left height 100%

Tags: html, css

I want the right grey section to be 100% height according to white section, on [this](http://hyindia.com/flex/parameters.html) website.

Comment: can you include the appropriate css and the html so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: Although it was meant as a joke, @Diodeus does have a valid point - you do not have a set height so you cannot set it as 100% (so the browser would see it as 100% of what?). A sneaky way to get around it is to position it absolutely and then set `top: 57px` (height + border of `#title`), `right: 0` and `bottom: 0` - that will force it to take the remaining space within `#reports-container`, but it is not the best way of doing it.

Comment: @Diodeus the question is clear, it's 100% height.

Comment: I guess you didn't see the question BEFORE it was edited.

Comment: @ArionaRian 100% of what? That's the point, obviously it's height, but 100% of what?

Comment: @Diodeus: 100% height !!

Comment: @Truth: 100% of the parent's height, just like 100% has always meant in CSS `height` properties.

Comment: I want right grey section to be 100% height, according to main white color container. Means when the accordion box increases then the height of main white container will be increased then right grey section look ugly. It should have 100% height to match the height of white container..Thanks!!!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Its a mistype because of fast typing, I am really sorry! and thank you for notifying me regarding a BIG mistake. I will never repeat this in life..

Comment: There's still no question here.

Comment: come on all, it's not english class, i bet you all have got the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with displaying element as table and table cell.
First you need to put the title outside the box (#report-container), and remove the floating property on both div inside #report-container (#text & .right-info), also the width value.
Then add this style :

```
#report-container{
   display:table;
}
#text , .right-indo { 
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align :top;
}
.right-info { 
   width : 217px; /* the size of the #text will be the rest */
}
```

See [my demonstration here](http://dabblet.com/result/gist/1845996/1da2b11568c7d712410ed36cc0a008cfe6432ff9).

You can try to resize browser window or add content to the #primary, and the #secondary height will be same.

Comment: Hello Ariona Rian, thanks but i am still facing 1 issue and i think you will help me..!!

the content of right grey section is now at bottom, please see this

http://hyindia.com/flex/parameters.html

Comment: i have edited the answer, i forgot to set the vertical-align to top :). Good luck and don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: Thanks you very much. Can i meet you on Skype ..?

Comment: i am not skype user, but you can chat with me on YM : yans_fied :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `position:absolute` for this write like this in your `css`

```
.right_info {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E8E8E8;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    min-height: 533px;
    padding: 44px 0 0 20px;
    width: 217px;
}
#reports-container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at your source code and came up with a solution yesterday for a similar problem that will be able to work for you, now it does use jQuery even though it is not specified, I noticed in your source you're using it and when it comes to `DIV` heights there aren't many options.

My blog post explaining what I have done can be found [here](http://siteconnection.blogspot.com/2012/02/re-sizing-elements-with-jquery.html).

In your case you want to get the height of 1 element and apply it to the other, there are other jQuery solutions to do this also - this one is designed originally to calculate the height of 2 elements and re-size a third as stated in the blog post.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var high = $(".right_info").height();
    $(".report_sec").height(high);
});
```

You can see a fiddle of this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8c92w/), note that the 2 `div` elements have different heights.

I hope this helps!